# Moving to another activity after successful Google login

Tags: android

I want to go to navigation activity after successful login with google but if user is already logged in then it should directly go to navigation activity otherwise first signin screen should be display,but this code is not working for me, can anybody tell me whats wrong with my code, splash is my default launcher activity.

My activity crash down just after splash screen.

Here is my navigation.java, signin.java, splash.java

https://gist.github.com/nabeelnazir163/241395d89919512722cc2b51d5f1bcee

Comment: What is the problem? Use `startActivity` with parameter of `Intent` class.

Comment: save login deatails and one loginstatus flag in shared preference and by that check it in splash sctivity. if loginstatus true then directly go to your activity else go to login activity

Comment: What is the crash log cat? Other thing is @BapusahebShinde explained, after successful login save login data or status in `SharedPreference` after whenever you start app check in splash screen that user is login or not and start activity as per your requirement ?

Comment: @BapusahebShinde how ?? can you write a code for me ? :(

Comment: add your log cat ?

Answer (score 1):

In your Splash.java in below line ,instead of getApplicationContext() use

> Splash.this

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),navigation.class);
```

As your code snippet is inside a different thread, save Splash.this value in some variable and then use it.

Move the code to Splash.java, where you are checking for if user is already signed in or not. If user is signed in already got to navigation screen, else go to signin screen.

Comment: May you show your logCat. It'll be very helpful to identify the cause of the crash.

Comment: Tell me the exact flow. After Splash screen you are directly going to Navigation screen?

Comment: yeah .. @Danger

Comment: https://gist.github.com/nabeelnazir163/9cf4671feaa5b39884f070e291bed909 logcat @Danger

Comment: Add another catch block for handling generic exceptions:                                       try {
                    sleep(1000);
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),navigation.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

}catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

}    may be here you'll catch something.